# How to find solutions to parametric differential equations as non-parametric level sets?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

Say that we have a parametric differential equation, given $g_k(t)$ and $h_k(t)$

$$\cases{\sum g_k(t)\cdot {f_x}^{(k)}(t) = 0\\\sum h_k(t)\cdot {f_y}^{(k)}(t) = 0}$$

with generalized "prime" notation $$ (\cdot)^{(n)}= \frac{\partial^n (\cdot)}{\partial t^n}$$

So that a curve is defined by $(x,y) = (f_x(t),f_y(t))$.

Can we transform this problem to a level set for some basis of functions:

$$\phi(x,y) =\sum c_k e_k(x,y) = 0$$

---

**Own work** An obvious example where this is possible would be the harmonic equations for sin and cos on the unit circle:

$$\cases{f_x(t) = \cos(t)\\f_y(t) = \sin(t)}$$
which solves $$\cases{g_k = \{1,0,1\}, f_x(0) = 1\\h_k = \{1,0,1\},f_y(0)=0}$$

and for which $$x^2+y^2 -1 = 0$$

What I am curious about is of course more general settings. Which areas of mathematics will I benefit from learning more from in order to be able to formulate and solve things like this?

---

A **suspicion** that I have is that $$(\nabla \phi (f_x(t),f_y(t))) \cdot [f'_x(t),f'_y(t)] = 0$$

In other words, the tangent of the trajectory of the parametric curve needs to be orthogonal to the gradient of the level set function.

Although I have no proof of this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level-set_method

Comment: @user807138 yes, that link leads to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation which might seem useful! Thank you.